# Common Lisp's symbol-name in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

Is there anything in Clojure that is equivalent to Common Lisp's
`symbol-name` function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Clojure name function will return the name of the symbol, instead of the symbol itself.

```
(name symbol)
```

[Answer by Stuart Sierra on Clojure group.](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/a0776bc5805a5137)